# Как узнать количество строк кода в проекте?

Tags: java, android, алгоритм

**Дано:**

Проект, состоящий из множества файлов (например `*.java` и `*.xml`).

**Задача:**

Подсчитать сколько [строк кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) во всех этих файлах. Исключая комменты и пустые строки.

**Вопрос:**

Пилить свой велосипед или я не первый кто этим интересуется?

Comment: А зачем это может понадобиться?

Comment: @PavelParshin, ну, например, для обоснования длительности внесения изменений в код... Или для хвастовства.

Comment: Ещё для оценки (очень приблизительной) прогресса в решении к-л (сферической) задачи (сферическим) кодером.

Comment: @PavelParshin, вот, на вики даже статья есть на тему зачем: [Количество строк кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо)

Comment: @PavelParshin для анализа проекта и его оценки. Очень актуально для подсчета генерируемого кода

Comment: `wc -l *.java `

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Решение задачи, в общих чертах, должно выглядеть так:

1. Собираем список всех файлов в проекте, пробежавшись по всем его папкам.
2. Считываем файл и считаем в нём кол-во строк
3. Регулярками (например) выкидываем из общего числа строк файла пустые строки и закомментированные строки (в зависимости от типа файла и ЯП, определяем как именно выглядит коммент)

---

И да, есть готовые решения. Например, вот на гитхабе: [Count Lines of Code](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc)

Вкратце алгоритм такой (для масдая):

1. Скачиваем `*.exe`.
2. Запускаем его из командной строки
3. Указываем папку с исходниками.
4. Получаем результат подобного вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.**

У *Count Lines of Code* есть множество [ограничений](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc#Limitations). Например `"/*"` `тут n строк кода` `"*/"` будут восприняты как **n** строк комментов. Также подсчёт идёт не логических строк кода, а *непустых строк, содержащих то, что программа определяет как код, а не комменты*.

Обратите внимание на приведённый в `README` проекта список альтернативных решений.

Comment: Никогда не думал об этом, но круто. Спасибо!

Comment: @dDevil, мне в голову ночью пришло, когда юзеры стали апдейта быстрее просить)))

Comment: @dDevil, Однако, не забудьте посмотреть https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc#Limitations

Comment: @avp, дополнил ответ, помянув об этом.

Answer (score 11):

Существует отличный плагин, с хорошими настройками. Отлично работает и для Kotlin с минимальным кол-ом действий.

1. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/4509-statistic скачайте
2. Установите **Install plugins from disk...** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3.Сделайте рестарт, внизу слева появится иконка **Statistic** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4.Нажмите refresh и увидите таблицу [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5.Настройки понятны и просты, удачи

Answer (score 0):

если под виндой работаешь то легко, используй cloc и следующие два шага:

1. открываешь терминал под админом и выполняешь=> `choco install cloc`
2. затем заходишь в папку с проектами через терминал и выполняешь=> `cloc project-example`

вот примеры на скринах:

1. [image]
2. [image]

p.s. нужно игнорить папку с билженным проектом и если у тебя веб то node_modules, можно их вынести или удалить

Comment: choco - это встроенная команда?