# Есть возможность получить статистику кол-ва строк Java кода в разных модулях в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Есть возможность получить статистику кол-ва строк Java кода в разных модулях (пакетах/папках) в IntelliJ IDEA? Может есть какой-то плагин?
В идеале, без пустых строк и импортов.

Я видел этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486414/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5), но хотелось бы без танцев с посторонними утилитами + там где надо у меня Mac и на него крайне не рекомендуется ставить/запускать что-то левое. Лучше, если поставил плагин к IDEA (еще лучше сделать штатными средствами IDEA, но я таких функций не нашел), нажал получить статистику и все.

**P.S.** Да я в курсе, что кол-во строк кода мало информативно, но тем не менее потребовалось для одного отчета менеджеру.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вполне вероятно что вам подойдет именно [этот](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4509-statistic) плагин. Функционал не такой обширный, но все же хоть какая-то статистика есть.